# How to get order shipping address data

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, importexport, shipping-address

> I'm trying to collect shipping address from order

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id, 'increment_id');
```

.......

```
 $order_Address= $order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true);
```

but it is printing me

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getFormated() on a non-object
```

but when I calling it like this it prints me **object**

```
$order_Address= $order->getShippingAddress()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `$order` is not set or it's no object *(of type `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`)*.

Also order with downloadable products have no shipping address.

**Edit:**

For the updated questions ... make sure loaded `$order` is valid. It seems the order you're are trying to load isn't correct.^

Use `entity_id`

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(19);
```

Use `increment_id`

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(300000024, 'increment_id');
```

You may add a check first

```
if ($order->getId()) {
    $order_Address= $order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true);
}
```

or

```
if ($order->getShippingAddress()) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
if ($order->getShippingAddress() instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: loaded order providing me other data correctly like.... $order_tax = $order->getTaxAmount();

Comment: Please manually check if there is an shipping address ... error says that `getShippingAddress()` has not returned an object.

Comment: Is a downloadable product ordered?

Comment: yes  print_r( $order->getShippingAddress()) ;   provides huge list of data and it also prints object ,  if ($order->getId()) {
    $order_Address= $order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true);
}... it also showing same error ...  products are simple products and three are gift card...

Comment: Whats output for `var_dump(get_class($order->getShippingAddress()))`?

Comment: repeating this words - bool(false) string(30) "Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62514/discussion-between-sv3n-and-user2366074).

Comment: The `bool(false)` should not be there! This shows that there is no shipping address. Seems as you call it two times ... second one (Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address) is correct.

Comment: @sv3n any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/315565/57334