# Magento 1.9 - How to display Shipping Address at the bottom of the invoice PDF?

Tags: magento1.9.2.3, edit, invoice-pdf

Following this [tutorial](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198402/57334) added following code to

**app/code/core/mage/sales/model/order/pdf/invoice.php**

```
  protected function _drawFooter(Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $store = null)
    {
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->drawLine(25, $this->y-200, 570, $this->y-200);

        $shippingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getShippingAddress()->format('pdf'));
        
        $page->drawText($shippingAddress , 35, $this->y-230, 'UTF-8');
    }
```

Getting error.

Expected result Scrrenshot : https://snipboard.io/dCTYWi.jpg

Comment: which error you getting?

Answer (score 1):

please refer the link below ,this may help you

https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/